# Why didn't android provide native support for autoresizing of text size in text view or buttons?

Tags: android-layout, android

I tried to do autoresize of text view. I came to know that android doesn't support it natively.

I found a few links like [Auto Scale TextView Text to Fit within Bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds) to do this. I just want to know why android didn't support it natively. Is there any specific reasons for it?

Comment: It makes more sense for the text size to determine the size of the textview rather than vice versa. Allowing for both usages would be a mess.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really useful for anything other than strings of text that may be replaced with long strings of text that require 100% visibility at all times.

DP & SP are units that are density-independent and scale-independent respectively. This allows the device, system, and user to adjust the sizes appropriately. You should always use SP for your text.